# Proper MySQL column type for bathrooms

Tags: mysql

I have a column in MySQL that is where we store the number of bathrooms a hotel has. What is the proper data type for this?

Hotels have full bathrooms and half bathrooms wherein "3.2" means 3 full bathrooms and 2 half bathrooms (no tub). I know I can't use decimal as it has different interpretation of "1.5" where instead of 1 full bathroom and 5 half bathroom it will interpret it as 1 and a half bathrooms. I don't think I can use string either as I will be needing some calculations later in the script to add or subtract between full and half baths. Also the data is sent to us by the hotel people so the format can't be changed, they are used to using "#.#" for their bathrooms.

Comment: their format can be "3.2" written in lipstick on a napkin. Do what Mark is suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question implies that you don't want "half"-bathrooms to be counted as half a full bathroom, you should store it as two separate fields (both integers) - one for full bathrooms, one for "half"-bathrooms. Splitting the supplied field into two should be part of your data load process.

Comment: I would shoot for a bigint :>